# Terraform IF condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working on AWS rds postgresql instance and we are using IAM authentication. I've created couple of roles, But for one role, I need to give a grant permission. I tried to use if condition but i'm getting an error that null values are not allowed for that attribute. I need to pass grant permissions for the users in the dev_role to access the db using IAM credentials.

What are other solutions, I could use to solve this error? I need to ignore the parameter.

```
# Create roles/groups
resource "postgresql_role" "pgauth_roles" {
  provider = postgresql.pg1
  for_each = toset(var.role_name)
  name     = each.value
  roles    = [each.value == "dev_role" ? "rds_iam" : null ]
}


  on ../../../../tf_module_amp_rds/pg_roles.tf line 14, in resource "postgresql_role" "pgauth_roles":
  14:   roles    = [each.value == "dev_role" ? "rds_iam" : null]

Null values are not allowed for this attribute value.
```

Terraform v0.12.20
+ provider.aws v2.60.0
+ provider.postgresql v1.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with an empty array `[]`
Something like this:

```
resource "postgresql_role" "pgauth_roles" {
  provider = postgresql.pg1
  for_each = toset(var.role_name)
  name     = each.value
  roles    = each.value == "dev_role" ? ["rds_iam"] : []
}
```

Comment: Some additional context as to why this worked: the original given example was producing a list _containing_ null, like `[null]`, which the provider's validation rules rejected. If `roles` is an optional argument then it could also work to set it to `null` (rather than `[null]`) to omit it altogether, but in this case I expect the provider would treat both of these as equivalent anyway.